# Changing marker's minimum zoom level

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm using Here Maps JS SDK. I'd like to change marker's minimum zoom level after creating a marker. My use case is about toggling clustering, where min zoom level must be set to Inf when clustering is disabled.

Thanks.

Comment: use `minZoom`variable when creating your map

Answer (score 1):

At this moment isn't possible change minimum zoom level *after* creating a marker.

As workaround you can move the necessary markers to your own ObjectLayer and then use method setMin see please example:

```
var parisMarker = new H.map.Marker({lat:48.8567, lng:2.3508});
map.addObject(parisMarker); //added to default ObjectLayer
myProvider = new H.map.provider.LocalObjectProvider();
var myLayer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(myProvider);
map.addLayer(myLayer);
myProvider.getRootGroup().addObjects([
    parisMarker //moved to custom ObjectLayer - myLayer 
]);
myLayer.setMin(8); //set minimum zoom level for all objects in the layer
```

See full example [set min zoom level for a layer](https://jsfiddle.net/vqa10kf5/)